# In asp helper tags, what is the difference between Model.PropertyName and just PropertyName

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Here is an example:

cshtml >>

```
<label>List of products: </label>
<select asp-items="Model.ListOfProducts" asp-for="ProductToSearch">
    <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

cshtml.cs >

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
   ...

    public SelectList ListOfProducts{get; set;}

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet=true)]
    public string ProductToSearch{get; set;} 
   ...
}
```

In cshtml why is one named Model.ListOfProducts but other one is named just ProductToSearch.
What does Model in this case do?

Comment: I'd guess because the item list could potentially come from somewhere external to the model, so you have to specify. Whereas in the `asp-for` you're supposed to always specify a model property. Simple test - what happens if you remove `Model` from the `asp-items` one? What happens if you add it to the other one?

Comment: P.S. https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/select-lists contains examples of `asp-items` pointing to things outside the model.

Comment: Thank you for responding. When i remove model i get an error, here is the error message: The name 'ListOfProducts' does not exist in the current context [ShopApp]csharp(CS0103).
And when i add model to the other property here is the error message i get:
'IndexModel' does not contain a definition for 'Model' and no accessible extension method 'Model' accepting a first argument of type 'IndexModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [ShopApp]csharp(CS1061)

Comment: That pretty much proves my point then, I think. Would you agree?

Comment: For me it's a bit hard to understand but i think i understand what you were trying to say, thank you for answering.

Comment: No problem. If the answer has helped you, please mark it as "accepted" below - thanks. (To mark an answer, click on the tick mark next to it so it turns green). Is there anything I can do to clarify it further, though? Do you understand the difference between data which is part of the Model object (which you pass to the View through the action method) and data which can be accessible from other classes in your project? That's essentially what we're discussing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list you supply to `asp-items` could potentially come from somewhere external to the model, so you have to specify the full namespace/class path to the object (or method to generate the object) you want to use.

Whereas in the `asp-for` you're expected to always specify a property from the current model, so there's no need to prefix it.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the actual types for those attributes on the tag helper(s). The `asp-for` attribute, for example, is backed by a property on the tag helper class that is typed as `ModelExpression`. As such, what you're passing to the attribute in the view is expected to be something that can be interpreted as a `ModelExpression`, i.e. a representation of a specific property at some level on the model. In other cases, such as with `asp-items`, the type is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, so you're expected to pass a value that is of that type.

Simply, the syntax of `@Model.Property` is a dereference: you're retrieving the value of that property, whereas when you just do `Property`, you're passing an expression *representing* that property.

There is a scenario that blurs the lines a bit: when the model is a list and you're specifically trying to reference a particular item in that list as an expression. In that scenario, something like `[0].Property` is not a valid expression, so you must use `@Model[0].Property`.